# Interleaving Strings Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the classic interleaving question with a slight twist. The twist is that the third string can be a interleaving of the first two string's loops. For example: Suppose str1="ABC" and Str2="ADC". Then the third string can be an interleaving of loops of "ABC" and "ADC". A loop would be any prefix of (string)^k, where k is some positive int. So a loop of A would be ABCABCA since it is a prefix of str1^2.

So a clarifying example would be the following:
str1 equals "ABC"
str2 = "ADC"
Str3 = "ABCADCABADCCA"- Find if str3 is interleaving of loops of str1 and str2.

"Answer: True because str3 is the interleaving of the loop: ABCABCA which is a prefix of str1^3 and loop ADCADC which is a prefix of str2. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point, I propose that the following algorithm is correct, with no comment on how optimal its runtime is:

1. Construct a DFA (let's call it L for "left") that accepts loops of the first string, e.g. `(ABC)*(e|A|AB)` where `e` is the regex that accepts the empty string.
2. Similarly construct a DFA (call it R for "right") that accepts loops of the second string.
3. We now construct an NFA (call it N for "nondeterministic") for your interleaving language as follows:

   - States N are pairs of states (l, r) where l is a state of L and r is a state of R.
   - There is an edge from (l, r) to (l', r') labeled c in N iff one of the following two conditions holds:

     - There is an edge from l to l' labeled c in L and r = r', OR
     - There is an edge from r to r' labeled c in R and l = l'.
   - (l, r) is final in N iff l is final in L and r is final in R.
   - The start state of N is (l, r) where l is the start state of L and r is the start state of R.

Then I think N accepts your interleaving language: accepting paths through this NFA correspond to a choice of assignment of either "L" or "R" to each character together with an accepting path through L for the characters labeled "L" and an accepting path through R for the characters labeled "R".

Just for fun, I've put together a very small implementation of this idea in Haskell, without trying to spend a lot of time doing optimization or anything like that. (So no minimization of DFAs, or trying to memoize state transitions, or anything like that.) It works okay for your example, at least:

```
import Data.List

type Position a = ([a], [a])
type DFAState a = (Position a, Position a)
type NFAState a = [DFAState a]

initialize :: [a] -> [a] -> NFAState a
initialize xs ys = [(([], xs), ([], ys))]

stepPosition :: Eq a => a -> Position a -> [Position a]
stepPosition x ([], []  ) = []
stepPosition x (bs, []  ) = stepPosition x ([], reverse bs)
stepPosition x (bs, e:es) = [(e:bs, es) | e == x]

ordNub :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
ordNub = concatMap (take 1) . group . sort

stepDFA :: Ord a => a -> DFAState a -> [DFAState a]
stepDFA x (l, r) = ordNub
                 $ [(l', r) | l' <- stepPosition x l]
                ++ [(l, r') | r' <- stepPosition x r]

stepNFA :: Ord a => a -> NFAState a -> NFAState a
stepNFA x ss = concatMap (stepDFA x) ss

evalNFA :: Ord a => [a] -> NFAState a -> Bool
evalNFA _      [] = False
evalNFA []     ss = True
evalNFA (c:cs) ss = evalNFA cs (stepNFA c ss)

top :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
top ls rs cs = evalNFA cs (initialize ls rs)
```

Here are some example runs in ghci:

```
*Main> :set +s
*Main> top "ABC" "ADC" "ABCADCABADCCA"
True
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main> top "ABC" "ADC" "ABCADCABADCCADABCC"
True
(0.01 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main> top "ABC" "ADC" "ABCADCABADCCADADCC"
False
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Could you explain you solution in more general terms? I'm trying to understand how i would make a table that could store the smaller instances of this problem like you do for many DP problems.

Comment: @jojo This is not a dynamic-programming-based solution. Trying to understand it as dynamic programming is a mistake. I'm not sure what "more general terms" means -- perhaps you can point to a specific piece of this exposition which is not clear.

Comment: Oh i see. I was looking for a dynamic programming solution to my problem. I'm really just trying to understand how i would tackle this problem so even psuedocode is helpful. My main concern is how i would determine what prefixes were used to create the third string.

Comment: @jojo I have explained how to tackle the problem, and given both pseudocode and actual, executable code. If you understand the ideas I proposed, it should be easy to see how to modify the code to give a more structured answer than `True` or `False`.